# Como posso fazer uma procedure para atualizar o saldo no postgres?

Tags: postgresql, trigger, stored-procedures, plpgsql

A minha vem dando um erro que eu nao consigo entender falando q está com erro no $, mas quando eu utilizei outra procedure de exemplo da internet quase nos mesmos moldes da minha deu certo, então o erro está sendo em como fazer a procedure.

A tabela operacao tem alguns campos, id_operacao pk, valor float, descricao varchar, tipo char(1), id_conta fk. E a tabela conta tem os campo id_conta pk, saldo float, nome. Quero que a procedure atualize o saldo da tabela conta quando houver alguma modificação na tabela operação.

Segue o código q estou tentando usar para fazer a procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION atualizasaldo(tipo char, valor float) RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
    if (tipo = 'E') then
        update conta 
        set saldo = saldo + valor
        WHERE id_conta = OLD.id_conta;
    elsif (tipo = 'S') then
        update conta 
        set saldo = saldo - valor
        WHERE id_conta = OLD.id_conta;
    end if;
END
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;

create trigger operacao_trigger after insert or update or delete on operacao 
    for each row execute procedure atualizasaldo(tipo, valor);

ERROR:  trigger functions cannot have declared arguments
HINT:  The arguments of the trigger can be accessed through TG_NARGS and TG_ARGV instead.
CONTEXT:  compilation of PL/pgSQL function "atualizasaldo" near line 1
SQL state: 42P13
```

Desde já agradeço a ajuda.

Solucionado:

Codigo da resolução:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION atualizasaldo() RETURNS trigger AS $$
DECLARE
    tipo char;
    valor float;
BEGIN
    if(TG_OP = 'DELETE') then
        tipo = OLD.tipo;
        valor = OLD.valor;
        if (tipo = 'E') then
            update conta 
            set saldo = saldo - valor
            WHERE id_conta = OLD.id_conta;
        elsif (tipo = 'S') then
            update conta 
            set saldo = saldo + valor
            WHERE id_conta = OLD.id_conta;
        end if;
        RETURN NULL;
    elsif(TG_OP = 'UPDATE') then
        tipo = NEW.tipo;
        valor = NEW.valor;
        if (tipo = 'E') then
            update conta 
            set saldo = saldo + valor
            WHERE id_conta = OLD.id_conta;
        elsif (tipo = 'S') then
            update conta 
            set saldo = saldo - valor
            WHERE id_conta = OLD.id_conta;
        end if;
        RETURN NULL;
    elsif(TG_OP = 'INSERT') then
        tipo = NEW.tipo;
        valor = NEW.valor;
        if (tipo = 'E') then
            update conta 
            set saldo = saldo + valor
            WHERE id_conta = NEW.id_conta;
        elsif (tipo = 'S') then
            update conta 
            set saldo = saldo - valor
            WHERE id_conta = NEW.id_conta;
        end if;
        RETURN NULL;
    end if;

END
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;

CREATE TRIGGER tg_operacao AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON operacao 
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE atualizasaldo();

Insert into operacao(descricao, valor, tipo, id_categoria, id_conta) values('Teste', 100, 'S', 1, 1);
```

Comment: Estou votando para fechar porque a pergunta esta recebendo BUMP, o AP parece ter abandonado ela e o AP postou a solução dentro da propria pergunta.

Answer (score -1):

No postgres para usar o controle condicional do fluxo do código, é utilizado o `IF ... THEN ... ELSIF ... THEN ... ELSE ... END IF`, conforme documentação.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONDITIONALS

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION atualizasaldo() RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
    if (TG_OP = 'DELETE') then
        update conta 
        set saldo = (select sum(valor) from operacao where id_operacao = OLD.id_operacao) 
        WHERE id_conta = OLD.id_conta;
    elsif (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') then
        update conta 
        set saldo = (select sum(valor) from operacao where id_operacao = OLD.id_operacao) 
        WHERE id_conta = OLD.id_conta;
    elsif (TG_OP = 'INSERT') then
        update conta 
        set saldo = (select sum(valor) from operacao where id_operacao = NEW.id_operacao) 
        WHERE id_conta = NEW.id_conta;
    end if;
END
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Comment: deu certo mais eu fiz a logica errada, agr nao sei como funcionar a certa kkkk editei a pergunta ve se vc consegue me ajudar ai